# Get array of alasset objects from urls

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get the urls of each alasset so I can send images with AFHTTPRequestOperation but I am having trouble getting a list of urls from my array of photo location strings

here is my code so far (doesnt work `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL defaultRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ed8170'`):

```
  NSLog(@"photos::%@",photoUrls);
        for (id photos in photoUrls){
            ALAsset *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:photos];
            NSLog(@"photoURL::%@",asseturl.defaultRepresentation.url);
```

photos log look like this:

```
photos::(
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=CE8A426B-3B59-4172-8761-CC477F3BB3EE&ext=JPG",
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=F4B68A42-1CA0-4880-9FB5-177CB091A28C&ext=JPG"
)
```

So basically I need the url for each asset so I can send them and am unable to figure out how to do this? I think all I need to do is convert my array of string urls to an array of assets but cant figure out how

updated code:

```
  NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:photos];

            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [library assetForURL:asseturl resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
             {

             }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
             {
                 // error handling
                 NSLog(@"failure-----");
             }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think this is valid:

```
 ALAsset *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:photos];
```

You can't assign an `NSURL` object to an `ALAsset` variable and expect it to magically change into that type.

You need to use the `ALAssetsLibrary` method `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:`. The result block will give you the `ALAsset` for the requested `NSURL`.

Comment: ok I have added that method but what do I put in the resultBlock to get the alasset (see updated code)

Comment: Put in whatever code you need to make use of the `ALAsset` parameter passed to the block. And your failure block should log the `error` parameter so you know why it failed.